# CMFCPropertyGridProperty questions

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ MFC application, and using a `CMFCPropertyGridControl` with  `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`. Wondering if it's possible to modify the behavior of the control so that the following occurs:

1. Looking to have the drop down arrow always appear on the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` where there are available options to choose.  Currently the user is required to double click on the row in order for the drop down arrow to appear on the control. Some users may not be aware there are other options to select.
2. When a user double clicks on the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` with 3 options to choose from, the control changes the currently selected option to the next option.  I don't want the option to change to another option unless the user specifically selects a different option using the drop down menu.
3. For a `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` with an enabled spin control, the spin control does not display until a user first clicks on the row in the property grid, and then double clicks on the property. I would like the spin control to always display.

   Any suggestions or help at all would be greatly appreciated.